# adding 30 minutes to datetime php/mysql

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, strtotime

I have a datetime field (endTime) in mysql. I use `gmdate()` to populate this endTime field.

The value stored is something like `2009-09-17 04:10:48`.  I want to add 30 minutes to this endtime and compare it with current time. ie. the user is allowed to do a certain task only 30 minutes within his endTime. After 30 minutes of his endTime, they should not be allowed to do a task.

How can this be done in php?

I'm using gmdate to make sure there are no zone differences.

Answer (score 133):

If you are using [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add) you can do it like this:

```php
SELECT '2008-12-31 23:59:59' + INTERVAL 30 MINUTE;
```

For a pure PHP solution use [*strtotime*](http://fr.php.net/strtotime)

```sql
strtotime('+ 30 minute',$yourdate);
```

Comment: This is the perfect solution for mysql and php. This should be marked as answer.

Answer (score 53):

Try this one

```
DATE_ADD(datefield, INTERVAL 30 MINUTE)
```

Answer (score 7):

MySQL has a function called [`ADDTIME`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html) for adding two times together - so you can do the whole thing in MySQL (provided you're using >= MySQL 4.1.3).

Something like (untested):

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE ADDTIME(endTime + '0:30:00') < CONVERT_TZ(NOW(), @@global.time_zone, 'GMT')
```

Comment: I came here looking for a generic way to add to datetime variables, and only this answer worked for me.

Answer (score 5):

Dominc has the right idea, but put the calculation on the other side of the expression.

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE endTime < DATE_SUB(CONVERT_TZ(NOW(), @@global.time_zone, 'GMT'), INTERVAL 30 MINUTE)
```

This has the advantage that you're doing the 30 minute calculation once instead of on every row. That also means MySQL can use the index on that column. Both of thse give you a speedup.

Answer (score 5):

Use DATE_ADD function

```
DATE_ADD(datecolumn, INTERVAL 30 MINUTE);
```

Answer (score 1):

Get date from MySQL table by adding 30 mins

```sql
SELECT loginDate, date_add(loginDate,interval 30 minute) as newLoginDate 
FROM `tableName`;
```

This will result like below

```
Login Date - 2020-07-22 14:00:00
New Login Date - 2020-07-22 14:30:00
```