# Adding time to mysql timestamp column, with condition

Tags: php, mysql

I have 3 time-related columns in my table:

```
vreme_od (TIME), vreme_do(TIME), datum(CURRENT TIMESTAMP)
```

`vreme_od` and `vreme_do` have `H:i:s` time values (the difference between `vreme_od` and `vreme_do` is 1 hour), `vreme_do` can be update from a script.

The thing is, I have to come up with a catch that updates `vreme_do` till a certain time, let's say, 21:00.

So, If you fire up the script at 20:53, for an example, `vreme_od` will have a value of "20:53:00", and `vreme_do` should have a value of "07:53:00" on the next day.

Can some one help me with this, I'm stuck for days with it...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436827/adding-30-minutes-to-datetime-php-mysql

Comment: I've managed to that, but the thing is with transfering time to another day, on certain condition.

Comment: Which should not cause any problems with the suggested way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using CASE statement, (global) example for update:

```
UPDATE table
 SET `date` = CASE
              WHEN CURRENT_TIMESTAMP>'23:00:00' 
              THEN CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 40 MINUTE
              ELSE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP END
 WHERE ...
```

Days will auto increment.

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out, it's a simple calculation, but I just didn't have inspiration... =)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [AddTime Function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_addtime) to add some hour in the second column using MySql built in function.

Comment: Could you explain that please?
I forgot to mention that I already have a table with predefined "work hours" of days in the week. Once again, if the start time (vreme_od) is 2012-08-29 20:30:00, the end time (vreme_do) should be 2012-08-30 07:30:30, and not 2012-08-29 21:30:00. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Can you please explain your question a bit? I got it kind of hard to understand your requirement properly

Comment: @user1481792 explain the columns briefly and add some example of your desired scenarios with critical inputs & outputs. Your problem should not be a very hard one and it should be easily solvable with plain php.So cheers :)