# Adding time to rows with a specific timestamp in a database

Tags: mysql, database, timestamp, sql-update

I have a database table that includes a timestamp for each record. Everyday this database is updated  by a cron that was set to run 1 minute before gmt midnight (23:59:00). We are changing the cron to run at exactly midnight now (00:00:00), so I need to update all fields that were logged at 23:59 to 00:00 of the next day (2013-05-21 23:59:00 should update to 2013-05-22 00:00:00).

The update script was set to capture the timestamp at script start, but because it was poorly written it didn't account for seconds so some records have a start time of 2013-05-21 23:59:01, some may have 2013-05-20 23:59:02 or even 2013-05-19 23:59:03. All of these will need to be updated to 00:00:00 of the next day.

There are thousands of other records that were not updated by the cron and therefore have random timestamps. **These records need to be left unaffected**. For example 2013-05-19 23:13:47, 2013-05-19 02:50:56, and 2013-05-19 16:42:13 should all be left untouched.

I think the following code from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12182475/adding-time-to-mysql-timestamp-column-with-condition) is somewhat along the lines of what I'm looking for, but after some googling and testing myself I haven't had much luck.

```
UPDATE table
 SET `time` = CASE
              WHEN CURRENT_TIMESTAMP>='23:59:00' 
              THEN CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 1 MINUTE
              ELSE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP END
```

Comment: Can the time be '23:59:15'?

Comment: Any time with 23:59:xx can be safely updated to midnight, although I think the latest cron I've found to run took place at 23:59:04 if it matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query -

```
UPDATE
  table
SET
  `time` = DATE(`time`) + INTERVAL 1 DAY
WHERE
  TIME(`time`) >= '23:59:00'
```