# Cast integer field into minutes

Tags: datetime, casting, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table in sql server 2008 r2. One of the fields in the table denotes how often a task runs. It is called `everyMinutes`. This field holds integer values, ranging from 0, to 15, to 120 and beyond. How can I select this field, and cast it as a time so that it may be added to other times?

I have `startTime` set as a `time(7)`. I recognize I could do what I'm about to ask in sql. However my end goal is to do it in php.

I would like to query `startTime` as well as `everyMinutes` so that they can be easilly added together in php. I'm looking for to cast, or convert, or something `everyMinutes` in the select statement so this can be done.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [DateAdd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

```
select DATEADD (mi,  everyMinutes, '1/1/2005' )
from table
```

EDIT:
If you want to do this in PHP, you can just select `everyMinutes` as is and then use [strtotime](http://fr.php.net/strtotime):

```
strtotime('+ 30 minute',$yourdate);
```

(Sorry, I don't know php, but you just need to build a string using `everyMinutes` and use as the first param.)

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1436844/1822514

Comment: I'm querying this table and bringing it into php. Is there a way I can bring `everyMinutes` into the select statement as some flavor of datetime?

Comment: @mhopkins321 - Maybe I am missing something, but it doesn't make sense to have `everyMinutes` as a date time. How do you add two dates together (1/31/2005 + 2/15/2025 == ??)

Comment: I suppose I don't necessarily mean datetime. But rather some sort of type that has time in it. I have made an edit to my post above