# Mysql datetime format add 10 minutes

Tags: mysql, triggers

Hi i have table with datetime variable. 
I was wondering if i can somehow change the datetime column to add 1O minutes to  stored date.
Perhaps some trigger has to be involved.

Thanks for help

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436827/adding-30-minutes-to-datetime-php-mysql) might help.

Comment: When do you want to add this 10 minutes, when you store the row? How do you store the row?

Comment: I was wondering if i can specifi column datetime format to add 10 minutest to value when is stored no matter how

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I like the [`INTERVAL expr unit`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add) notation. It feels more readable to me:

```
SELECT NOW(),
       NOW() + INTERVAL 10 MINUTE;


+--------------------------------+-------------------------------+
|             NOW()              |  NOW() + INTERVAL 10 MINUTE   |
+--------------------------------+-------------------------------+
| August, 12 2013 14:12:56+0000  | August, 12 2013 14:22:56+0000 |
+--------------------------------+-------------------------------+
```

If you want to select existing rows and add 10 minutes to the result:

```
SELECT the_date + INTERVAL 10 MINUTE FROM tbl;
```

If you want to alter existing rows stored in a table, you could use:

```
UPDATE tbl SET the_date = the_date + INTERVAL 10 MINUTE;
```

If you want increase by *force* a value by 10 minutes while inserting, you need a trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER ins_future_date BEFORE INSERT ON tbl
FOR EACH ROW
  SET NEW.the_date = NEW.the_date + INTERVAL 10 MINUTE
```

Answer (score 2):

add 10 minute in following way

```
       SELECT  ADDTIME(now(), '1000');
```