# How to add some amount of time from now?(MySQL)

Tags: mysql

How can I add certain amount of time from now in mysql?

```
INSERT INTO rank(id, username, rank_type, time_start, time_end, activated) 
VALUES (NULL, 'somename', 1, NOW(), DATE(NOW() + INTERVAL 30 DAY), 0);
```

It says syntax error. I think the problem is caused by DATE function. Also tried to use NOW() + INTERVAL 30 DAY, but it didn't work either.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mysql datetime format add 10 minutes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18188056/mysql-datetime-format-add-10-minutes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `DATE_ADD(date,INTERVAL expr type)` is what you are looking for..

```
INSERT INTO rank(id, username, rank_type, time_start, time_end, activated) 
VALUES (NULL, 'somename', 1, NOW(), DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY),0);
```

Some documentation can be found [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_add.asp)

Here is an [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c8dc8/1)

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't in the date math.   Just leave off the second parameter to DATE(), 
as in:

```
INSERT INTO rank(id, username, rank_type, time_start, time_end, activated) 
VALUES (NULL, 'somename', 1, NOW(), DATE(NOW() + INTERVAL 30 DAY));
```

Here's an SqlFiddle:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f479f/1