# SQL SELECT WHERE datetime is between NOW() interval

Tags: sql, mariadb

how can I select in **MariaDB** between two dates (in this case between two minutes)? I mean I want to select between from now() +5 minutes and now() + 30 minutes.
I tried with this query but no luck.

```
SELECT req_id FROM info WHERE date(sent_date) BETWEEN (NOW() - INTERVAL 5 MINUTE) AND date(sent_date) < (NOW() - INTERVAL 30 MINUTE)
```

Thank you so much for helping.
BTW, I tried to search answer to my question in stackoverflow but I don't found.

Comment: What is the data type f sent_date?  Should the dates be the other way around > -30 and <-5?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [adding 30 minutes to datetime php/mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436827/adding-30-minutes-to-datetime-php-mysql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax of your `WHERE` clause is off.  Use this version:

```sql
SELECT req_id
FROM info
WHERE sent_date BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 5 MINUTE AND NOW() - INTERVAL 30 MINUTE;
```